# Git merge fails in AzureDevOps pipeline in local works fine

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-merge

I have two git branches

- source_branch
- target_branch

And I want to merge "source_branch" into "target_branch" using one Azure DevOps pipeline, both branches are created by the same parent, and the "source_branch" have one simple change of difference, but when execute merge instruction this process failed.

The task is a PowerShell Task

[PowerShell Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQED0.png)

This is the powershell script:

```
git config --global user.email "build@azuredevops.com"
git config --global user.name "buildazuredevops"
git fetch
git checkout source_branch
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
git checkout target_branch
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
git checkout source_branch
git merge target_branch --allow-unrelated-histories
git checkout target_branch
git merge source_branch --allow-unrelated-histories
git push
```

And this is the log result:

[Log detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8jdf.png)

```
Switched to a new branch 'source_branch'
branch 'source_branch' set up to track 'origin/source_branch'.
Already up to date.
Switched to a new branch 'target_branch'
branch 'target_branch' set up to track 'origin/target_branch'.
Already up to date.
Switched to branch 'source_branch'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/source_branch'.
Auto-merging Apps/Admin/Admin.ControllerServices/Account/Query/AccountSetupControllerService.cs
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Apps/Admin/Admin.ControllerServices/Account/Query/AccountSetupControllerService.cs
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
error: you need to resolve your current index first
Apps/Admin/Admin.ControllerServices/Account/Query/AccountSetupControllerService.cs: needs merge
error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
Everything up-to-date
```

The problem is this:

```
Switched to branch 'source_branch'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/source_branch'.
Auto-merging Apps/Admin/Admin.ControllerServices/Account/Query/AccountSetupControllerService.cs
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Apps/Admin/Admin.ControllerServices/Account/Query/AccountSetupControllerService.cs
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

But the "source_branch" only have a change in one file, and this code works ok in my local computer, and the "merge" and "push" workly successfully.

Which can be the problem?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was that I checked out the repo using the `checkout` task. I fixed it by cloning the repository using `git clone` instead .

**Note:** If you choose to do it with `git clone` and want to push your changes to the repository, you might need a [Github Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).